# unlink doesn't work

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to use unlink command on my server Apache/2.2.3 PHP Version 5.2.10. I have been using the same script on a bunch of other servers including my local PC. Unfortunately, the command doesn't work.

I tried this so far:

- `chmod` everything to `777`
- putting new files and unlinking them
- also I notice that I can't upload or saveXML files to the server

I am guessing that it is some kind of setting inside the `php.ini` file, but I don't know which.

Comment: What is the error you get? There should be an E_WARNING on false.

Comment: post an error message. be more specific about what is "not working"..

Comment: @Vadim: If you found your solution, post it an answer and accept it. Don't write solutions in questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Checking if it is writable first and then unlink it seem to do the trick

```
if (is_writable("$bannerlink")) unlink("$bannerlink");
```

thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)?